# Language switching with Mobility Gem

Tags: ruby, globalize, mobility

How can I create a language toggle with the Mobility gem? Coming from Globalize I was using:

```
<% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale  %>
  <% Globalize.with_locale(:fr) do %>
   <%= link_to "Français",  url_for(slug: @page.slug, locale: 'fr') %>
  <% end %>
<% else  %>
  <% Globalize.with_locale('en-ca') do %>
  <%= link_to "English",  url_for(slug: @page.slug, locale: 'en-ca') %>
  <% end %>      
<% end %>
```

But this isn't working with Mobility.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, for anyone else that has the same issue:

```
For French
<%= link_to "Français", I18n.with_locale(:fr){page_path(@page, locale: 'fr')} 

For English
<%= link_to "English", I18n.with_locale('en-ca'){page_path(@page, locale: 'en-ca')} %>
```

Answer was found here: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id-globalize/issues/7